# Getting METADATA of currently played audio in Android

Tags: android

I have created an application to get METADATA of currently played audio with the help of mediaPlayBackService in FROYO.

Now when I am trying it on GingerBread SDK it is crashing as mediaPlayBackService is made local service.

Is there any way by which I can bind with this service or any other way by which I can get META for currently played Audio.

Thanks,

Swapnil

Comment: Is there any way you could share how you did that as im looking to do the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

I found out one solution to get the METADATA of currently played song.

For getting metadata,

1. Create a Intent filter with following Actions:
   PLAYSTATE_CHANGED
   META_CHANGED
   PLAYBACK_COMPLETE
2. Register our application with above IntentFilter
3. In onReceive function we will get the bundle as follows:

   ```
   Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
   ```
4. This bundle will contain the new/changed MetaData. We can get TrackID like

   ```
   long  trackId = (Long) bundle.get("id");
   ```
5. With the help of track ID we can query the database and get other details of Audio    file being played. (I have not tested but the same bundle should give other properties of audio file too)

Only problem is that, if the audio file is already being played (i.e. before starting our application), we will not get any broadcast on start of our application and hence NO MetaData is available, on next audio change we will get the updated values.

Hope this help all who all looking for same stuff.

Thanks,
Swapnil